# convert a variable dictionnary in a dataframe to multiple variable

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a variable "Location" which looks like :

```
0   "{'latitude': '47.61219025', 'longitude': '-122.33799744', 'human_address': '{""address"": ""405 OLIVE WAY"", ""city"": ""SEATTLE"", ""state"": ""WA"", ""zip"": ""98101""}'}"

1   "{'latitude': '47.61310583', 'longitude': '-122.33335756', 'human_address': '{""address"": ""724 PINE ST"", ""city"": ""SEATTLE"", ""state"": ""WA"", ""zip"": ""98101""}'}"
```

I want to have 6 new variables in my dataframe named latitude, longitude, adress, city, state, zip.
i don't succeed to convert my "location" variable in 6 new variables since 2 hours.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5dqb.png)
Can you help me pleased?
Thanks

Comment: I try using a dictionnary : dictionnary_location=dict(Location) but it doesn't work. I try using regular expression but i don't succeed. I don't keep the code.

Comment: I have no code yet.

Comment: I have no code yet. I have one variable named 'location' in my dataframe as i explain. i want to decompose this variable in six new variables in the same dataframe. i want to have a variable named 'latitude' with 47.61219025 for the observation 0 and 47.61310583 for the observation 1, ...                                                                                                                       obs   latitude          longitude         … zip
0 47.61219025 -122.33799744 … 98101
1 47.61310583 -122.33335756 … 98101

Comment: i spend two hours on this problem without working code. i don't succeed to create a dictionnary with a variable from dataframe. Could you share some tips and after i present to you the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert value in your `Location` to dict

```py
import ast

df['Location'] = df['Location'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

def eval_nested_dictionary(x):
    x['human_address'] = ast.literal_eval(x['human_address'])
    return x

df['Location'] = df['Location'].apply(eval_nested_dictionary)
```

Then use [pandas.json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to create dataframe from nested dict.

```py
df_ = pd.json_normalize(df['Location'].values.tolist()).rename(lambda x: x.replace('human_address.', ''), axis=1)
```

```
print(df_)

      latitude      longitude        address     city state    zip
0  47.61219025  -122.33799744  405 OLIVE WAY  SEATTLE    WA  98101
1  47.61310583  -122.33335756    724 PINE ST  SEATTLE    WA  98101
```